# I can't star chat messages as a new Stack Exchange employee

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but as a new employee I can't star things in team chat.

I've created this question to highlight my problem, but to also resolve it. (hoping that by generating some rep my problem will be solved)

Updated for clarity:

Here's the message I get:

> [image]

If there's another term for the internal chat we use on the meta board, I'm happy to hear it (team chat seemed to fit..)

Comment: I was going to close this as off topic then looked on your profile... what is "team chat"? Is this some specific room?

Comment: Also, what happens when you try to star? You see any error message popping up, or in the JS console?

Comment: I hadn't realized Stack Echange was a company. :P

Comment: We just change Es, not genders, like some other companies do, expertly.

Comment: Does it say "You do not have sufficient reputation to vote" ? If so, I suspect we can override that for internal rooms ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell just give him a diamond, won't it solve everything?

Comment: Updated question for clarity.  Thanks for pointing out my missing X =)

Comment: Cheers @Dan, now I'm totally curious about this secret room of yours! ;)

Comment: Wait, you didn't get your glitter sticky stars? For the first few days, you need to use those (just put them right on the screen next to the message you want to star) You should have been issued a pack when you started, odd.

Comment: @TimPost I've applied glittery stickers, but now my screen is obscured.  Please assist.

Comment: @Dan You could make another post, a feature-request to use transparent sticky stars.

Comment: Wow, 86 repz from one innocent question. So easy! :)

Comment: @TimPost I hope you were referring to this skit... if not you will be pleasantly amused.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question was in fact enough to push my rep up over the required minimum of 20 for starring chat.

Thank-you

Comment: Well, now we're going to have to downvote you so we can validate the change I just made...

Comment: So many ups and downs on your first day. Literally.

Comment: I WAS JOKING !! I WAS JOKING!! (stop downvoting him, please...)

Comment: @MarcGravell Too late!

Comment: Rep fell below 20 due to downvotes... I can no longer star - I'll open a new question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Dan! :)

Answer (score 7):

This should work for company rooms in about 90 seconds.